# yocto: changing keyboard layout support in core-image-sato

Tags: keyboard, yocto

I want to add different keyboard layout - like arabic or persian - to the core-image-sato , unfortunately I have no idea how and where to search for it. can anyone give any hints or solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Although I do not know the `core-image-sato`, this answer probably helps you. In my case I wanted to load swiss german keymapping for the console on startup. I therefore wrote a small systemd-service that launches `loadkeys` with a custom keymap.
All wrapped in a bitbake recipe:

kbdlayout.bb:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Setup a default (german) keyboard-layout for the console only"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/LICENSE;md5=3f40d7994397109285ec7b81fdeb3b58"

inherit systemd

PV = "0.2"
PACKAGE_ARCH = "voisee"
SRCREV = "HEAD"

SRC_URI = "file://kbdlayout.service \
           file://de_CH-latin1.bmap \
          "


do_install () {
    install -d ${D}/${sysconfdir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/de_CH-latin1.bmap ${D}/${sysconfdir}/keymap.map

    install -d ${D}/${base_libdir}/systemd/system
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/kbdlayout.service ${D}/${base_libdir}/systemd/system/
}

NATIVE_SYSTEMD_SUPPORT = "1"
SYSTEMD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "kbdlayout.service"

FILES_${PN} += "${base_libdir}/systemd"
```

kbdlayout/kbdlayout.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Loads custom keymap if available
ConditionPathExists=/etc/keymap.map

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/loadkeys /etc/keymap.map'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then you need your actual layout file (in my case `de_CH-latin1.bmap`) placed in the folder `kbdlayout` besides the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

I came here asking for the same thing, and I assume you have probably fixed it as the question is quite old. I found the answer by surfing through recipes, and you have to:

-include the package kbd-keymaps anywhere (for instance in your local.conf through IMAGE_INSTALL_append).

-check /usr/share/keymaps/ to see everything is in there.

-load any keymap by using "loadkeys" (should be included in your distro, if not, force it same way).

HTH.